Identify SOT23-6 smd marking code 169 324
This chip in electronic load DL24M, please help me identify it.
pin 4 it's out
and connected with pin 1 LM321 (on 4pcs lm321)




is the component detective? ... the sloppy soldering may be the problem

It's a Shanghai Belling (上海贝岭) BL1551B SPDT analog switch. The package is SC70-6, not SOT23-6. That's why dimensions are important for identification questions.


(Source: lcsc.com)
